# UIToolbar standard sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiresponder

What are the standard sizes of a UIToolbar for the following:

**iPhone/iPod**

- iPhone 3.5 inch vertical
- iPhone 3.5 inch horizontal
- iPhone 4 inch vertical
- iPhone 4 inch horizontal

**iPad**

- iPad vertical
- iPad horizontal

Comment: It's regular `UIToolBar` object.

Comment: @Desdenova Oops - of course you're right. Input accessory view is a standard UIToolbar. . Re-phrased question, because still can't find the summary of sizes that I need.

Comment: It's height is 44px. Full Width depending on the orientation.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`UIToolBar` width is **equal to the width of the containing view**. Height is 44px.

Answer (score 4):

This webpage might be helpful: http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html It provides an overview on standard sizes of UI elements.

Comment: this table has mistakes. Example - table claims "Tab bar icon" size has 30x30 pts. But it's up to 48x32 pts according https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html